# what is the best procedure to store bulk list of images as blobs in browser cache?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image-caching, localforage

Currently i am using localForage and caching axios request which stores image blobs with over 2 gb image list , user frequently uses this images so i need to cache this in browser

Answer (score 0):

2GB of size is not **cacheable** what you can do is load fragment of the image that the user asks for try using [openseagragon library](https://openseadragon.github.io/)
I used it to view on web images up to 7GB of size

Comment: its not a single image i am having a dropdown of items which have images and dropdown list have 10000 items and using virtualized list to show them

Comment: Exactly we were producing huge number of images and you can see how fast it is